# Laravel transactions - associate model to other model while creating the first one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, transactions, eloquent

I have two models: UserPayout and UserTransaction where UserTransaction is polymorph and needs to know which model it belongs to. Whenever a user creates a payout, a transaction should automatically be made. If something went wrong in this process, both should get rolled back.

I already asked this question some time ago and got this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32040189/1233206

Today I tried to implement it as follows:

```
# Controller

$user_payout = new UserPayout($input);
$user->payouts()->save($user_payout);

# TransactionHandler

// event: creating
public function onPayoutCreation($event)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try{
        $transaction = new UserTransaction(
            array(
                'user_id' => $event->user_id,
                'value' => -$event->amount
            )
        );

        $transaction->creator()->associate($event);
        $transaction->save();
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        DB::rollback();
        throw $e;
    }

    DB::commit();

    return true;
}

// event: creating
public function onTransactionCreation($event)
{
    $user = User::find($event->user_id);
    $user->balance = $user->balance + $event->value;

    if(!$user->save()) throw new Exception('User could not be saved. Check for validation rules.');

    return true;
}

public function subscribe($events)
{
    $events->listen('eloquent.creating: UserPayout', 'TransactionHandler@onPayoutCreation');
    $events->listen('eloquent.creating: UserTransaction', 'TransactionHandler@onTransactionCreation');
}
```

Well, according to the linked answer the foreign keys should be set. Laravel indeed is setting the foreign_type as "UserPayout" but the foreign_id is NULL.

What am I doing wrong here or doesn't it simply work this way? How can I achieve what I want?

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: I assume your $event variable is a Model, does it have an "id" field ?

Comment: Yes, it's the UserPayout-Model as you can see in the subscribe() function on the bottom of the code block. It has an ID field but it isn't created at the moment the associate() function is called so in this case it has no ID set until it's finally created.

Comment: that's exactly the problem, there is no 'id' to be set in foreign_id, so the UserPayout must be inserted before doing the rest of the stuff, which means you shouldn't listen to "creating"

Comment: Thanks but then the whole transaction thing wouldn't make any sense. It's very important to insert the UserPayout model only when all other models were set too. If something went wrong the UserPayout must get rolled back. How can I achieve this then?

Comment: well i think you should do it as i said in the earlier comment, however you should begin your transaction before creating UserPayout and commit it afterwards, so it'll be something like:


1- BEGIN TRANSACTION

2- create UserPayout

3- on UserPayout saved: UserTransaction

4- on UserTransaction saved: update User balance

5- END TRANSACTION